# Size of a single Record ? SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a scenario where every user has been allocated 2 MB of database space.
Now I have to show Percenatge usage of their allocated space, to do so I need to know the size of single record in the Table.

I have tried to use sp_spaceused and even wrote a custom procedure making use of datalength .. but they show vast difference in their result.

Is there any way around to get this thing right.

Comment: What is this "space" used for?

Comment: How are you partitioning your user data ? Is it all in the same table ? Or does each user have their own tables ?

Comment: I have one Table where all user data is saved. UserId is used to differentiate individual user data

Comment: @Sandhurts: what do you consider to be userdata? The entire record in your Table? Just one column of that Table? Should an index on that table be taking into consideration as being userdata?

Comment: the entire record for that user in the table as well as index comprises userdata

Comment: So by optimizing your table by adding indexes, it might be possible for users to exceed their allocation?! If you are showing the usage percentage to your users, this could become very confusing.

Comment: possibly show us your try, and ask what could be done to improve it or find the problem why it is not giving good results

Comment: I think the unfortunately reality is there is no "good answer" to your question as it pertains to your specific problem.  The reason being is even if you determined the actual data space consumed by each row, associated each of those rows with the user, and then determined which of those rows belonged to what data pages, you won't achieve 100% accuracy.  The results will always be fuzzy at best since there's always some loss of resolution due to how the storage engine works.  It may be time to consider an alternative method to implementing your quotas, such as the number of rows.

Answer (score 25):

Run [DBCC SHOWCONTIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx) with your table name

```
dbcc showcontig ('TableName') with tableresults
```

then look at max min and average record size

Comment: what is the unit of that sizes you mentioned are they KB or B

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx - Looking at this I believe it is Bytes

Comment: FYI, according to the linked MSDN page: "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats instead."

Comment: When I compare the results from this to "measuring" records using datalength (e.g. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25532/24058 ), I get very different answers for mins and maxes.  datalength accounts for var(max) datalength, which is a LOB so maybe shouldn't count depending on what OP wants.  however the min from sum of datalengths is much smaller then the min given by DBCC SHOWCONTIG.

Answer (score 12):

The following query will tell you the percentage of @SpaceAllotted that is being used by the data by looking at how many pages are allocated by the database's objects.

It's not worth attempting to measure usage at the row-level, since SQL Server allocates all space at the extent-level.  Each extent is composed of eight 8KB data pages.  So if your database only had one row, and that row had 4 bytes of data, an entire extent would still need to be allocated to hold that 4 bytes (or an existing extent with unallocated pages would be used.  This is called a mixed extent).

```
DECLARE @SpaceAllotted      FLOAT
-- 2MB converted to kilobytes...
SET     @SpaceAllotted = 2048

SELECT 
    -- Allocation is done on the extent-level.
    -- Each extent contains eight 8KB data pages.
    ((1 / (@SpaceAllotted)) * CEILING(CAST(SUM([ips].[page_count]) AS FLOAT) / 8) * 64) * 100 AS PercentageUsed
FROM
    [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats](DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) ips
    -- This will allow us to retrieve the page count of all tables in the
    -- current database, regardless of whether or not they have clustered
    -- indexes and/or non-clustered indexes.
INNER JOIN
    [sys].[indexes] i
    ON
        [ips].[object_id] = [i].[object_id]
    AND [ips].[index_id] = [i].[index_id]
```

Since we do have the possibility of mixed extents, and no *good* way (there are ways, but they're not going to be pretty) of determining what pages are allocated to what extents, this isn't 100% accurate.  Additionally, extents may even have free pages (that are reserved and therefore still taking up disk space), so generally, this estimate will always come in low.  However, it's probably the best you're going to get without writing something to inspect the database at the page-level.

Ah yes, looking at the other answers, this is another option.  This will basically look at all the current size of the data files in pages, and determine the percentage of the space they have consumed.  Now, there are caveats here as well...

- If there's no maximum size specified for the database (autogrowth is enabled and unrestricted), this won't fly, since *max_size* will be returned as **-1**.
- Again, we can't accurately determine how much space is used by the actual data.  Here we're looking at how much space is actually used on the file system.
- We're not looking at log file space.  Yes, that does still consume disk space.

Hope one of these solves your problem.

```
SELECT 
    ((1 / CAST(SUM([df].[max_size]) AS FLOAT)) * CAST(SUM([df].[size]) AS FLOAT)) * 100 AS PercentUsed
FROM 
    [sys].dm_io_virtual_file_stats(DB_ID(), NULL)   vfs
INNER JOIN 
    [sys].[database_files]  df
    ON 
        [vfs].[file_id] = [df].[file_id]
WHERE 
    [df].[type] = 0
```

Answer (score 12):

Since showcontig is going to be deprecated, you can also use:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
(DB_ID(N'DatabaseName'), OBJECT_ID(N'TableName'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED')
```

Answer (score 10):

You can calculate the size a row (of number of rows) with a fairly complex formula. See [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189124.aspx) (ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/udb9/html/81fd5ec9-ce0f-4c2c-8ba0-6c483cea6c75.htm) for the exact details.

In short:

Take the number of columns and determine the size of each column by its datatype for fixed-length datatypes.

Calculate the space used for any nullable columns
Then calculate the rowspace:

Row_Size = Fixed_Data_Size + Variable_Data_Size + Null_Bitmap + 4

Answer (score 1):

The data is saved on disk in directories named for the database. That includes everything, including what you're not measuring (indices, etc.). Measure that.

Comment: How to measure those any hint will be useful