# How find size of selected rows in a table of Sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find size of selected rows in a table of `Sql server`.
Notice: I have `Sql Server 2012`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771248/size-of-a-single-record-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 One way is to look at the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats output.
```

The min_record_size_in_bytes, max_record_size_in_bytes and avg_record_size_in_bytes will give you the sizes you want.

```
If you want to see the size of a particular record, another way is to find the physical row location, see
```

[SQL Server 2008: New (undocumented) physical row locator function.](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-new-undocumented-physical-row-locator-function/)

You can then dump the row physical structure, see Anatomy of a Record.